# Ссылки в старых комментариях

Tags: поддержка, статус-отклонено, локализация, комментарии

[Пример комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/56292/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5#comment56340_56292):

> Если на сервере стоит Apache, то можно использовать директивы [CustomLog][1] и [LogFormat][2] для вывода в логи записей требуемого формата. [1]: httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog [2]: httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat – Nicolas Chabanovsky♦ 23 ноя '11 в 12:43

Предположу, что раньше комментарий был виден пользователям так, как ниже, но впоследствии что-то поломалось:

> Если на сервере стоит Apache, то можно использовать директивы [CustomLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) и [LogFormat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat) для вывода в логи записей требуемого формата. – Nicolas Chabanovsky♦ 23 ноя '11 в 12:43

Вопрос: планируется ли включить поддержку Markdown-конструкции `[имя ссылки][номер ссылки] [номер ссылки]:ссылка` в комментариях, или старые комментарии так и останутся в столь неприглядном виде?

Comment: Это не единственная проблема со старыми комментариями: на старом сайте комментарии поддерживали полноценное форматирование. Правда это тот редкий случай, когда есть поддерживаемая альтернатива.

Comment: @Discord, к сожалению, я не очень понял, о какой «поддерживаемой альтернативе» речь.

Comment: Имею в виду, что синтаксис с вынесенными ссылками должен был быть преобразован в синтаксис с инлайновыми ссылками.

Comment: Тогда почему бы не выгрузить старые комментарии и пройтись по ним самописным парсером? Мыжпограммисты!

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, какого–то автоматического парсера, который сам все преобразует, не планируется. Как мне кажется, таких комментариев не так много, и эффективней будет просто руками подправить, при обнаружении.

Comment: Я думаю, парсер мы сможем и сами написать.

Comment: Руками комментарии? Эм.. Такая функциональность есть только у модераторов ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy Пожалуйста, просто упомяните меня в чате, при необходимости, добавив ссылку на комментарий. Я с удовольствием поправлю.